# I am trying to send json structure to a web server

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to send json structure to a web server 
But, every time I get the eror

Here is my code, hope you can help me:

First of all, it is the structure that I should send to the server:

```
{
   "UDID": "UDID - limited to 5 calls per day" 
   "Hazard": {
     "TypeID": 3, 
     "Info": "Some Information" 
     "Name": "User Name", 
     "Phone": "User Phone" 
     "Email": "User Email" 
     "FBID": "User FaceBook ID", 
     "LocationLat": "LocationLat", 
     "LocationLng": "LocationLng", 
     "LocationDesc": "Location Description", 
     "Image": "a Base64 Image" 
     "Extension": "jpg, gif, etc ..." 
   } 
}
```

Response Success

```
{
  "error": 0,
  "Serial": "string : some serial number"
}
```

Response Fail

```
{
  "error": 1,
  "errdesc": "Invalid Lat/Lng ,Type ID, etc..."
}
```

Now, as you certainly see these two libraries, so, here they are created:

Here we creating libraries

```
NSMutableDictionary * Hazard; 
     NSMutableDictionary * maindic; 
NSString  TypeID = @ "TypeID"; 
    NSString  info = @ "info"; 
    NSString  Name = @ "Name"; 
   NSString   Phone = @ "Phone"; 
  NSString    Email = @ "Email"; 
   NSString   FBID = @ "FBID"; 
    
   NSString   LocationLat = @ "LocationLat"; 
    NSString  LocationLng = @ "LocationLng"; 
    NSString  LocationDesc = @ "LocationDesc"; 
    NSString  Image = @ "Image"; 
    NSString  Extension = @ "Extension"; 
    
    
     Hazard = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 0, TypeID, @ "", info, @ "", Name, @ "", Phone, @ "", Email, @ "", FBID, @ "", LocationLat, @ "", LocationLng, @ "", LocationDesc, @ "", Image, @ "", Extension, nil];
```

Hazard dic set:

```
[Hazard setValue: textField.text forKey: Name];
```

Phone,Image... And so on

And now here the problem, when the user clicks on the button the following code is activated...

```
NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];



    maindic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:uuidString,@"UDID", Hazard, @"Hazard", nil];

    NSData *DATA = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:maindic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:0];


    NSLog(@"JSON summary2: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:DATA
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"myserverblalal.com"];


    NSString *data_length = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[DATA length]];



    NSMutableURLRequest *MyRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url
                                                                     cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:60];

    [MyRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST" ];
    [MyRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [MyRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [MyRequest setValue:data_length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    [MyRequest setHTTPBody:DATA] ;


    NSURLResponse *response;


    NSData *POSTRE = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:MyRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTRE bytes] length:[POSTRE length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

This is the response I get from the server

Reply: {"error": 1, "errdesc": "Invalid UDID"}

Does anyone could help me, and tell me why I am getting the eror

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, please have a look at some coding guidelines (for iOS and in general) - your code is quite a mess, and will be barely readable for others and probably yourself in the future. Especially mixing variable names with capital letters, underscores, small letters, all capitals, camelCase - it's all there ...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the server didn't like the UUID that you sent it.

Notice that you created a UUID (which is just a random 128 bit number encoded as a string), but the key is "UDID" and the error complains about an invalid "UDID". UDID is a Unique Device Identifier, that is a code that identifies one particular device, for example one particular iPhone. UUID is a Universally Unique Identifier - something totally different.

UDIDs are not supported anymore for privacy reasons; as a replacement you would calculate a UUID once and store it in UserDefaults.

You better talk to the people running the web server and find out what they are expecting.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response, 

Second, - 
I thought maybe my mistake lies in the code sending the request to the server 

For example: 
I took my udid number from ituns 

And put it into my library just so 

     maindic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: myudid, @ "UDID", Hazard, @ "Hazard", nil]; 


Still, I got the response: 

2014-02-20 01:57:40.438 Hazard [155:60 b] Reply: {"error": 1, "errdesc": "Invalid UDID"} 

Perhaps, if there is no problem in my code, I need to get in touch with the people who work on the server 

Thanks anyway :)